# PHP artisan serv not working after composer dump

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have managed to "fix" the issue, but to tell you the truth I am not sure why it was an issue in the first place and what I did in order to fix it which is why I am posting the question:

**Question:**

When I was updating my composer.json file to include:

```
"files": [
    "app/helpers.php"
    ]
```

After running (in terminal):

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

php artisan serv no longer initializes a server - there is no error message - it just goes to the next ready prompt.

**Solution I used:**

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Then

```
composer update
```

Comment: Have you checked log files?

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned above I used:

Solution I used:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Then

```
composer update
```

Reason behind it was a simple glitch in my ***composer.json*** file where I added:

```
"files": [
    "app/helpers.php"
    ]
```

it was not inside the brackets of the autoload preset.